# "I shall not go unless you do not accompany me" -Is this correct?

Tags: grammaticality

This was another sentence found in an university question paper to make correction.

> "I shall not go unless you do not accompany me."

Is the correction to do with changing "shall" to "will" ? or anything else?

Comment: This university question paper is probably from the 1940s.  They tend not to keep up with the times.  A contemporary speaker would be likely to say *I won't go if you intend to come along.*

Comment: This is just nonsense!  It literally means the same as "If you come with me, I shall not go."  or  in proportional logic  "I go  AND you go  IMPLIES  NOT I go"  Which is a false proposition.  In other words... this is just nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I would question the 'do not'. A more natural statement would be 'I want you to accompany me. I shall/will not go unless you accompany me'. But there's nothing *grammatically* wrong with saying 'I don't want you to accompany me. I shall/not go unless you do not accompany me' - in other words 'I shall/will not go if you accompany me' or 'I shall/will not go unless I go alone or someone else accompanies me'. But we would need more context to decide that that was the 'correction' intended.

Comment: I am pretty sure that 'unless' conveys determination, and sufficient context is thus supplied, so that the traditional choice between shall and will can be made.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I don't think the question is about will/shall; I think it's about the _unless,_ "I shall not go unless you accompany me." Strike the "do not".

Answer (score 0):

In modern usage, shall and will are often used interchangeably, however the traditional rule is that shall is used with first person pronouns (I, we) to form the future tense, while will is used with second and third person forms (you, he, she, it, they). For example: I shall be hungry, they will be late. However, when expressing a strong determination, these are reversed: will is used with the first person, and shall with the second and third. For example: I will not tolerate such behaviour, you shall go to the ball! Thus, a traditionalist would correct 'shall' to 'will' in your example sentence.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824090357/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/shall-or-will)

Comment: In an English-speaking community I know of nobody who is aware of any distinction between the uses of *shall* and *will* - and they're pretty smart folk in other respects. Most of the time all one hears is **I'll** - make of it what you will!